# Are there n positive integers, such that $z_1^2+z_2^2 +…+z_{n-1} ^2=z_n^2$, for every $n>1$?

Tags: number-theory, integers

I know it is truth for the first few $n$-s but, is it truth for all n > 0?

I tried by induction, but got stuck!

Comment: This seems relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: I can't find the question I answered that this duplicates, but the idea is the LHS should begin as $3^2+4^2$, then keep extending by adding $z_{n\text{new}}=\frac{z_{n\text{old}}^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: $${x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+...+{x_i}^2 ={x_{i+1}}^2 $$ $$x_1=2{p_1}s$$ $$x_2=2{p_2}s$$ $$....$$ $$x_i={p_1}^2+{p_2}^2+{p_{i-1}}^2-s^2$$ $$x_{i+1}={p_1}^2+{p_2}^2+{p_{i-1}}^2+s^2$$